# theory specification multiple return statement inside a function

Tags: c++, function, return

I am wondering if the return statement is immediate when a condition occurs without any exception.

In particular I've a BOOL function:

```cpp
bool pm2_filter( std::string gnomad_ex_controls_an, std::string gnomad_gen_controls_an, std::string &gene_inh_mode )
{

    if ( gnomad_ex_controls_an == "NA" && gnomad_gen_controls_an == "NA" ) { 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if ( gene_inh_mode == "dom" || gene_inh_mode == "NA" ) {
            if ( gnomad_ex_controls_an != "NA" ) {
                if (std::stoi(gnomad_ex_controls_an) == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if ( gnomad_gen_controls_an != "NA" ) {
                if (std::stoi(gnomad_gen_controls_an) == 0) {
                  return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if ( gene_inh_mode == "rec" ) {
            if ( gnomad_ex_controls_an != "NA" && floatable(gnomad_ex_controls_an) ) {
                if (cmpf(std::stof(gnomad_ex_controls_an), 1E-4, 1E-10)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if ( gnomad_gen_controls_an != "NA" && floatable(gnomad_gen_controls_an) ) {
                if (cmpf(std::stof(gnomad_gen_controls_an), 1E-4, 1E-10)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to run it in this manner it warnings me:

```cpp
dependencies/filterFunctions.cpp:403:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
```

to avoid the warning I can put a final `return` to the function, e.g.

```cpp
bool pm2_filter( std::string gnomad_ex_controls_an, std::string gnomad_gen_controls_an, std::string &gene_inh_mode )
{

    if ( gnomad_ex_controls_an == "NA" && gnomad_gen_controls_an == "NA" ) { 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if ( gene_inh_mode == "dom" || gene_inh_mode == "NA" ) {
            if ( gnomad_ex_controls_an != "NA" ) {
                if (std::stoi(gnomad_ex_controls_an) == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if ( gnomad_gen_controls_an != "NA" ) {
                if (std::stoi(gnomad_gen_controls_an) == 0) {
                  return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if ( gene_inh_mode == "rec" ) {
            if ( gnomad_ex_controls_an != "NA" && floatable(gnomad_ex_controls_an) ) {
                if (cmpf(std::stof(gnomad_ex_controls_an), 1E-4, 1E-10)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if ( gnomad_gen_controls_an != "NA" && floatable(gnomad_gen_controls_an) ) {
                if (cmpf(std::stof(gnomad_gen_controls_an), 1E-4, 1E-10)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // FINAL RETURN:
    return false;

}
```

but I'm wondering if this `return` at the end of the function is effectively returned ONLY ADN IF ONLY NO other previous `return` is met, without exception.

I tried to figure it out on the web nut found no specific answer, so I'm asking you expert guys.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: Your indentation is idiosyncratic so it's hard to see where the run-off potential is. Could you please reformat?

Comment: Yes, the return at the end of the function is performed if-and-only-if none of the other returns have been performed.  In case all the other if-checked returns are exhaustive, then the final return is dead code, and could be replaced with a `throw` statement.

Comment: edited @Bathsheba, works better?

Comment: One-liners are poor engineering because they don't allow to set a breakpoint and ruin code coverage and profiler source code annotation.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Sometimes there is, exceptions might be thrown in destructors of automatic objects for example.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, I just thought about it

Comment: @cccnrc It's not much better. Stick to one of the established conventions. Folk in my shop who can't format code decently end up working in the Python team.

Comment: @Bathsheba why would you put people who can't format code onto a Python team?    Just curious

Comment: @Drt: 'cuz you're pretty much forced to indent in the correct places.

Comment: removed any one-liner and indented else etc. Is that ok @Bathsheba? PS: is that really easier for you guys to understand the function working in this style? No critics, just curious

Comment: @cccnrc: Indeed it is. The formatting you present (2 character indent *is* acceptable although unfashionable) is nearly perfect, but at least the code is readable now.

Comment: what is the "official" one? 4-chracter indent? other differences with my formatting? @Bathsheba

Comment: @cccnrc: I use K & R with 4 characters and no tabs with the exception that I don't use a space in `) {`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style. Too old to change now! Some IDEs have a "format" option to sort out messy code.

Comment: edited, that would be a correct K&R 4-char indentation @Bathsheba? sorry to bother but I want to learn for next times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

```
// FINAL RETURN:
return false;
```

Will only run if none of the other `return`'s are reached.  The reason you get the warning is if

```
if ( gnomad_ex_controls_an == "NA" && gnomad_gen_controls_an == "NA" )
```

is false then you go into the else part and if

```
if ( gene_inh_mode == "dom" || gene_inh_mode == "NA" )
```

is false then you go to

```
else if ( gene_inh_mode == "rec" )
```

and if that is false then you fall out of all the condition and reach the end of the function.  It is undefined behavior to not return from a function that is supposed to return something so you get an error.  It may be that it is impossible for your data set to reach that, but the compiler can't know that so it warns you.